# sum the count of days in many intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sum, datediff

I have the following table:

```
CREATE table DataDiff (CLI tinyint, id tinyint, date datetime, countable bit)
insert into DataDiff values (234,1,convert(datetime,'17/12/1997',103),1)
insert into DataDiff values (234,2,convert(datetime,'09/07/1998',103),0)
insert into DataDiff values (234,3,convert(datetime,'11/08/1998',103),1)
insert into DataDiff values (234,4,convert(datetime,'29/12/1998',103),0)
insert into DataDiff values (234,5,convert(datetime,'01/02/1999',103),1)
insert into DataDiff values (234,6,convert(datetime,'03/02/1999',103),0)
insert into DataDiff values (234,7,convert(datetime,'03/02/1999',103),1)
insert into DataDiff values (234,8,convert(datetime,'29/03/1999',103),0)
insert into DataDiff values (234,9,convert(datetime,'29/03/1999',103),1)
insert into DataDiff values (234,10,convert(datetime,'31/03/1999',103),0)
```

I am having a hard time rewriting, without RBAR, a UDF to count the days from ID=1 up to ID=2 then from ID=3 to ID=4 and so on, always starting the count when COUNTABLE=1 and stopping when COUNTABLE=0 and then return the sum for a given CLI.

The length in days of the five intervals pictured is:

```
ID=2 - ID=1  = 204
ID=4 - ID=3  = 140
ID=6 - ID=5  = 2
ID=8 - ID=7  = 54
ID=10 -ID=9  = 2
```

for a total of 402 "countable" days from the total of 469 days between ID=1 and ID=10

Comment: What if you have an odd number of days?

Comment: @Justin Satyr Do you mean if the last COUNTABLE=1 ? Well in this case it counts up to the present day.

Comment: You really didn't define what `COUNTABLE` is.

Comment: @Justin Satyr COUNTABLE is just a marker to know when a date must start being counted and when the count must stop. It refers to procedures to start/stop sending editions in magazine subscription.

Comment: @pistipanko IS_AVAILABLE is the old name of COUNTABLE, please waive that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select t1.cli ,
       sum(t1.countable  * 
           datediff(day, t1.[DATE], coalesce(t2.[DATE],getdate())) ) daycount
from DataDiff t1
left join DataDiff t2 on t1.cli = t2.cli and t1.id+1 = t2.id
group by t1.cli
```

(Assumes that if the last recorded date for the cli is countable, then it should be counted up to the current date.)

Comment: This may be a bit off-topic, sorry, but just to be sure I understand your idea well and perhaps to be also sure to make myself clear enough in similar cases in the future: when you ("you" = "people who speak English as their first language") say "up to… (some date)", does that have any implication as to whether the "some date" is included into or excluded from the range, or is there no such implication by default? I used to think there *was* an implication and the date was included, but if I were now to judge by your query, it would seem in fact just the other way.

Comment: @AndriyM: I think "up to" would *tend* to mean *including* the last date, but this would not necessarily be definite - context could provide clarification. In this case, I have assumed that the current date is the next *applicable* date.

Comment: Oh, so in the end it's *up to* one's context, I see. :) Makes sense, thank you very much!

Comment: Still, as to your solution, I'd like to point out that your query would *not* count the current date, because in fact it does not count the last dates (which are effectively the start dates of uncountable periods). And that's exactly how I would count it (i.e. excluding the last days, like you do).

Comment: tough I didn't thoroughly understood your logic, it appears to be a nice piece if code, but it gives me incorrect results 864, as opposed to a expected 402. I've edited the question text to make it clearer.

Comment: If I group by ID in your solution, I can see it counts 15 rows, as it counts twice the IDs 2,3,5,6,7.

Comment: @LynxKepler: I have just run my query with the data in your question - I had to correct the name of the table and add an extra `)` to the `sum` expression (answer updated accordingly) - and it returned 402. Can you check wether there is other data in your table? (I have been assuming that CLI and ID together uniquely identify records in your table.)

Comment: I don't know where the 864 came from! I just run it again and it returned  402! Thanks very much! This answer was very helpful!